# Ubuntu Touch - Screen lock activating while transferring files

Tags: ubuntu-touch, lock-screen

Yesterday I added a few songs/albums from my laptop to my Ubuntu tablet. The process was very easy and it was a pleasure to be able to do something so easy. However, after I had connected the tablet to the laptop and searched for my songs, I was then unable to add the files. This is because the tablet lock had kicked in after 1 minute. So I had turn off the tablet 1 minute lock, move the files over and then set the 1 minute lock again.

Is there a setting that I can activate to allow save the tablet lock activating while I am adding files/songs to my tablet?

On the whole, a really smooth process for adding music to my tablet.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try **[Active Screen](https://uappexplorer.com/app/activescreen.mivoligo)** app by Michal Predotka as a workaround.

Comment: I have installed it and it does appear to be good. Thanks for the suggestion. It woild be good if this was automatic when moving files, so I think I will add this to Launchpad.

Comment: There  was a similar question in the past. I think a bug / feature request was raised, so that Ubuntu touch does not lock screen while the device is connected via USB...

Comment: http://pad.lv/1580479 and http://pad.lv/1580174